# Parameters of partial renders, ROR3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have this hack to make the partial render work, because the partial render only works with the instance variable @product. I'm pretty sure it's not the best way to work this out, can someone please point a better way?

```
 <% products.each do |product| %>
    <% @product=product %>
    <%= render 'cart_form', :product => @product %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to render a collection here without using the .each loop. Take a look at the [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and try something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "cart_form", :collection => @products %>
```

(and set @products in your controller)